# Numlist limits in Stata lower than -help limits- suggests

Tags: stata

I am using a Stata command, `synth`, that takes a *numlist* as an argument.

I need the *numlist* to take 2,000+ values.  Note that `forvalues` is not a viable work-around in this context, unless I am mistaken.  I am using Stata MP 13.1.  In `help limits` it says that the size limit for a *numlist* is 2,500.  However, when I run the following code, I receive error code "r(123) invalid numlist has too many elements."

```
foreach i of numlist 1/1601 {
   display `i'
}
```

This code runs without an error:

```
foreach i of numlist 1600{
    display `i'
}
```

Is there a way to allow a larger *numlist* than 1,600 elements?  Also, why does `help limits` tell me I have 2,500 to work with, but not allow more than 1,600?

Edited to add: `nlist`, used to parse a *numlist*, specifies a maximum of 1,600.  So perhaps 1,600 is the proper maximum?  In that case, the `help limits` page seems to be incorrect.

Second edit to add: `synth` is a matching command, and you provide it with a *numlist* of control units to include in the matching procedure.  So if you have a panel with 2000 units and 10 time periods, you might specify 1,999 units to be included as potential control units.  It might be possible to use `forvalues`, but it would require editing the `synth` ado file somewhat significantly.

Comment: `numlist "1/2500" ` works for me in 14.1. I surmise that the limit that is biting you is an undocumented limit for `foreach` (which I agree should be  documented as such). I can't comment on `synth` and in any case you should say more about how a _numlist_ is used with `synth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try concatenating the lists of numbers, or use `forvalues`:

```
set more off

// option 1, or some variation
numlist "1/1600"
local firstlist `r(numlist)'

numlist "1601/1603"
local all `firstlist' `r(numlist)'

foreach i of local all {
   display `i'
}

// option 2
forvalues i = 1/1603 {
   display `i'
}
```

`forvalues` is documented as being faster, so use that, if you can.

There is a limit for "# of characters in a macro", depending on the Stata flavor, as documented in `help limits`:

> 8,681
>   165,200
>   1,081,511

### Update

This however doesn't work:

```
foreach i of numlist `all' {
   display `i'
}
```

reporting

> invalid numlist has too many elements
>   r(123);

So if the user-written command parses as *numlist*, you might have problems with that too. My suggestion is to try and report back.

Comment: I missed your original comment on `forvalues`. Just ignore, if not viable.

Comment: I'm not sure if the macro limit applies, but if it does I don't think I am hitting it.  The numlist elements are all 2 or 3 digits, with single spaces, so a numlist of 2,000 elements would only be 8,000 characters at most.  Unless I am missing something?  Also edited to add more info about how -synth- uses the numlist.

Comment: Tried your concatenating suggestion, Roberto.  The -synth- option (required) for control units is -counit(numlist)-.  I concatenated three lists and did -counit(`all')- and received the same error: "counit() invalid -- invalid numlist has too many elements."  There is an unnecessary step in the -synth- .ado file that grabs labels for the control units, and it seems to be the only place that parses as a numlist.  I think it might be possible to remove that section, so I might reconfigure the ado and try that.

Comment: Yes, as expected. Modifying the _.ado_ file might be your way out. If you have problems with that, post another question, probably linking back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find the *numlist* error easily in the .ado file. I am getting around this issue by selecting a subsample of donors for the synthetic control, with the number of groups equal to the limit of *numlist*. In my case I want to keep most of the donors that are logically in the proximity (geographically or similar population or other characteristics) of the treated unit. I subsample those first and I fill up the limit with additional units selected randomly.